# Error while comparison in Array : Segmentation fault

Tags: c++

Code is Something Like :-

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int array[6]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5 ; i++){
        for (int j = 5; j <= i ; j--){
            if(array[i] + array[i+1] == array[j]){
                cout << array[i] << " + " << array[i+1] << " = " << array[j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am beginner actually and my teacher gave me a question and when I solve it , I got error . Please tell me what's the error.

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger? Those things can really help narrow down the problem.

Comment: it's an out of bounds error. can you notice it? it's almost trivial

Comment: And your nested loop will only execute when i = 5. Check that.

Comment: Never post code that is "something like...".  Always post "this is a small self-contained code sample that produces the exact problem."

Answer (score 2):

In your second condition, `for (int j = 5; j <= i ; j--){` you decrement `j` but test if `j` is less than `i`. It will always be true. 
Moreover, `j` will become -1 thus the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(array[i] + array[i+1] == array[j]){
```

You run that line of code when `i == 5`. Which means you test `array[6]`, which is out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

In the last iteration of your loop "for i", i has the value 5.

You then access the element array[i+1] i.e. array[6], which does not exist. The array values are array[0], array[1], ..., array[5].

Answer (score 0):

Try this code!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int array[6]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
    for (int i = 0; i <5  ; i++) //Fix 1
    {  //Run this loop till array[4] because in if condition you are accessing array[5] which is the last element of array
        for (int j = 5; j >= i ; j--) //Fix 2
        { //Run this loop till j is greater than i 
            if(array[i] + array[i+1] == array[j])
            {
                cout << array[i] << " + " << array[i+1] << " = " << array[j] << "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 + 2 = 3
2 + 3 = 5
```